# sequelize - get AVG of included model

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

I have a a schema that is like `product: { ... ,ratings: [ {rating: 3} ] }`, and using sequalize, I would like to add on a property `product.avg_rating` using `sequelize`.

Here is **my code**:

```
sequelize.models.product.findAll({
    include: [{
       model: sequelize.models.rating,
       as: 'ratings', 
       attributes:  {
        include: ['rating',[sequelize.fn('AVG', 'ratings.rating'), 'avg_rating']]
       },
       group: ['rating.rating'],//also tried ratings.rating, and just rating
    }],
 }).then(products=>{...})
```

But I keep getting this **error**:

> In aggregated query without GROUP BY, expression #1 of SELECT list
>   contains nonaggregated column 'text_rewriter.languageCombination.id';
>   this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by

**Goal Output:**

```
products: [
   {product: 'product name',
    ...
    ratings: [...],
    avg_rating: 3.7 //THIS AVG IS WHAT I WANT
   },{...}
]
```

any ideas what I am missing? I have seen many examples, but none of them use include like I did that I found.

Comment: Did you ever solve this?

Comment: @bob_cobb nope I had to do it after the db call.

Answer (score 0):

```
sequelize.models.product.findAll({
include: [{
   model: sequelize.models.rating,
   as: 'ratings', 
   attributes:  ['avg_rating'] //this is column name here
}],
}).then(products=>{...})
```

This will return :-

```
products: [
 {product: 'product name',
 ratings: [...],
 rating : { //here all the attributes you wanted, in this case only 'avg_rating' }
 },
 {...}
]
```

But you have to define relastionship between products table and rating table before using this.

Table : Product have id, name

Table : Rating have id, rating, product_id

In above case relationship will be 'rating.belongsTo(product) OR product.hasMay(rating)'

Answer (score -1):

MySQL implements detection of functional dependence. If the `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY SQL` mode is enabled (which it is by default), MySQL rejects queries for which the select list, `HAVING` condition, or `ORDER BY` list refer to non-aggregated columns that are neither named in the `GROUP BY` clause nor are functionally dependent on them.

The error is related to `sql_mode`, you need to execute the following command on your database console.

```
SET GLOBAL sql_mode = '';
```